# Create grid in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to create a grid like this: [Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaVEF.png)

I'm using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 366; i++) {
        $('#div-padre').append('<div class="dia" id="div'+ i +'" /> ');
    }
});
```

to generate 365 divs, then, with CSS, create the 'grid' style.

```
.dia {
      width: 45px;
      height: 45px;
      background: white;
      outline: 2px solid;
      float: left;
  }

  .div-padre {
      width: 800px;
  }
```

I tried to clearfix but the last div goes wrong, I don't care if they are divs, tr or whatever, but in the future i would like to select one square and change color, so div or tr or something, I need you to be able to do that later

Comment: try to append `.append($('<div/>', {id: 'div-'+i, class: 'dia'}))` instead, to create an element before appending

Comment: Can you use css grid? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout IF so, it's just a case of writing some css. And for the record, don't update html in a loop, push the new html text to an array and update it once after the loop, will save you alot of rendering time.

Comment: Use `overflow: hidden` on `#div-padre`.

Comment: NB: Your code will actually create *366* divs :P

Comment: Also better to build the necessary html first as a string and append the string *once*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a border/outline management issue, take a look at this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 366; i++) {
        $('#div-padre').append('<div class="dia" id="div'+ i +'" /> ');
    }
});
```

```css
.dia {
      width: 45px;
      height: 45px;
      background: white;
      border: 2px solid;
      float: left;
      margin-top:-2px;
      margin-left:-2px;
  }

  .div-padre {
      width: 800px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-padre"></div>
```

Comment: Okay, it works, thx, im from spain, creating 365 divs with for on jquery its a good practice? Or there are another shape of doing the same but more efficient? Thx

Comment: May be creating all divs before appending to the DOM have better performances

Answer (score 1):

Use `border: 2px solid; margin: -1px;` instead of `outline: 2px solid;`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
        $('#div-padre')
        .append(
         $('<div>', {
           id: 'div-' + (i+1),
            class: 'dia'
          }));
    }
});
```

```css
.dia {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: -1px;
  float: left;
}

.div-padre {
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-padre"></div>
```